# Why is it called hypochondria instead of hyperchondria?

Tags: word-choice, roots

If hyper essentially means excessive and hypo means the opposite then how does this word make and sense?

It seems like some people decided to improperly make a word out of Greek terminology but admittedly I can't translate it very well or find a good source. I did read something about it meaning under the breast bone somewhere, which hypo (under) makes sense, but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: How does [this](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hypochondria) not explain it???

Comment: ***If*** hyper meant excessive and hypo meant the opposite, you might have a point...

Comment: Just look it up in a [dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hypochondria).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is named after the [hypochondrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypochondrium), the uppermost  part of the abdomen. This was believed to be the region of melancholy and morbid feelings -- such as thinking you are sick when you aren't.

Answer (score 1):

---

According to [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/hypochondriac/)

> Hypochondriac comes ultimately from the Greek word hypokhondria, which
> literally means “under the cartilage (of the breastbone).” In the late
> 16th century, when hypochondriac first entered the English language,
> it referred to the upper abdomen.

---

It derives from the Greek word:

> υποχονδρία

Etymology:

> υποχονδρία < αρχαία ελληνική ὑποχόνδριος (ὑπό + χόνδρος)

ὑπό = sub, under, insufficient

χόνδρος = chondriac, or as @Mary said, the uppermost part of the abdomen

---

To understand better, the word "hyper" or "υπέρ" has a different meaning.

υπέρ = hyper, super, over, excessive

Therefore,
υπέρ ≠ ὑπό

Comment: The OP already knows that *hyper-* and *hypo-* have the opposite meanings. What the OP needed explained is what chondros is, and what that part of the body has to do with hypochondria; all that was already explained by @Mary. Also, *hypochondria* entered into English from ancient Greek, so the quotations from what appears to be a dictionary of modern Greek are of limited relevance.